How to change the favicon using next js
I have problem that the favicon does not change when searched in google.
This is the _document.tsx and the image exists in public folder.
but it still take the last logo and not change to the new one
 <Html dir={dir}>
    <Head>
        <meta property="og:image" content={`https://ghrafy.com/favicon.ico`} />

        {/* <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
         /> */}
         <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
         <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Kufi+Arabic:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
          

    </Head>
    <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
    </body>
</Html>


Use favicon
Basically the meta og:image is a favicon, and the favicon is the icon that appears next to the website name, usually using og:image Only Used for websites that can be searched on google, So instead then use this code to change the favicon
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <title>Your website name</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/path/to/your/icon">
    </head>
    <body>
  <p>your stuff here</p>
    </body>
</html>


<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
you can use this code instead of existing favicon link tags.
Ensure that you have cleared the cache in your browser and tested the favicon change in an incognito window to see the updated favicon.
